# org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils$ScriptLoadException: Could not load classpath init script with Micronaut project using Test-Resources

Tags: java, micronaut, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

I am stuck on this since two days, while I am trying to implement the Test-resources capability of Micronaut framework.

Here is the content of my application-test.properties :

```
datasources.default.dialect=MYSQL
datasources.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
datasources.default.schema-generate=CREATE_DROP

test-resources.containers.mysql.image-name=mysql:8.1.0
test-resources.containers.mysql.db-name=testDB
test-resources.containers.mysql.username=dbuser
test-resources.containers.mysql.password="mypassword"
test-resources.containers.mysql.init-script-path="src/test/resources/init.sql"
```

My `pom.xml` is declaring the common micronaut dependencies (generated from the Micronaut Launch app).

Anyway, I always have the following error when trying the `mvn clean test` command.

```
[test-resources-service] 15:33:37.784 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] INFO  tc.mysql:8.1.0 - Container is started (JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:53931/testDB)
[test-resources-service] 15:33:37.785 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] WARN  org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils - Could not load classpath init script: "src/test/resources/init.sql"
[test-resources-service] 15:33:37.785 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR tc.mysql:8.1.0 - Could not start container
org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils$ScriptLoadException: Could not load classpath init script: "src/test/resources/init.sql". Resource not found.
        at org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils.runInitScript(ScriptUtils.java:347)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.runInitScriptIfRequired(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:332)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.containerIsStarted(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:187)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.containerIsStarted(GenericContainer.java:712)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:532)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:344)
        at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:322)
        at io.micronaut.testresources.testcontainers.TestContainers.getOrCreate(TestContainers.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.testresources.testcontainers.AbstractTestContainersProvider.resolve(AbstractTestContainersProvider.java:100)
        at io.micronaut.testresources.server.TestResourcesController.resolve(TestResourcesController.java:90)
```

In the Micronaut documentation it is mentioned that it has to be a file in the `classpath`.
[Micronaut Test-Resources doc](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test-resources/snapshot/guide/#modules-databases)

My guess here is that the classpth does not use the same root as my java project.

I tried different values for `test-resources.containers.mysql.init-script-path`.

- Relative path using the project root as reference
- Absolute path (not sure it is the best solution, but at least it confirmed that even an absolute path couldn't be resolved)
- using the `classpath:` prefix for the relative path of the init script (ex : classpath:src/test/resources/init.sql")
- using the declaration from the Testcontainers documentation ([init script in Classpath](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#using-a-classpath-init-script) & [init script from a file](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/#using-an-init-script-from-a-file)

None of them even worked.

Anyway I am sure the other part of the Test-Resources module are working well because when I don't declare an init script, the database is used but none of the expected tables are present.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something in the configuration?

Edit : I am using the standard controller and CrudRepository from Micronaut. I just found appealing to use the Test-Resource for integration purpose.

Comment: When having `init.sql` in folder `src/test/resources/`,the file will end up in folder target/test-classes after build, and you'll use `classpath:init.sql` . Normally, you would create a folder called e.g. scripts inside folder `resources`, then use `classpath:scripts/init.sql` BR

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but no success doing this. As already said in the thread, I tried every form of declaration I thought of, same result each time.

Comment: Can you verify that the file is copied to target/test-classes after build ? BR

Comment: Indeed it is (target/test-classes/scripts/init.sql) ! I can't really understand why it is not found by the ScriptUtils class. I took a look at the sources of the Testcontainers dependency and it uses "Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(initScriptPath)" to find for the resource. Any idea why it is not resolved as supposed?

Answer (score 0):

update script path to following it worked for me.
after adding script under db folder it works.

src\test\java\resources\db\schema-postgresql.sql

```
@Container
private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:11.1")
            .withDatabaseName("db").withUsername("test").withPassword("test")
            .withInitScript("db/schema-postgresql.sql");
```

OR

```
private static final String initScriptPath="db/schema-postgresql.sql";
ScriptUtils.runInitScript(new JdbcDatabaseDelegate(postgreSQLContainer,""), initScriptPath);
```

Also make sure that these folder exist under target/test-classes before running Tests.
if not than copy manually or setup through maven resource plugin to copy it.